Growing plants on Mars
I've just been watching Scott Manley's video on Elon Musk's early plans to demonstrate a "greenhouse" growing relatively-familiar plants on Mars 


He mentions that seeds would be in "eggbox-like" cells filled with a gel growth medium, which would at an appropriate point be hydrated from a water container provided it had not frozen (otherwise energy would have to be expended to thaw it).
Since there are numerous plants which can survive temperatures well below zero, and since a growth medium could presumably be engineered to be relatively insensitive to temperature, this makes the water supply particularly vulnerable in this type of experiment.
Leaving aside the possibility of an antifreeze mix (e.g. water plus some proportion of ethylene glycol) ** , could the water be replaced by some other compound with a lower freezing point which would either be processed by the growth medium or accepted directly by the plants?
** Updated: I feel I need to be more specific here. While my initial curiosity related to some alternative compound which the plant could in some way convert to H2O when needed, I'm not necessarily discounting an aqueous solution or mixture which could depress the freezing point while leaving H2O available for uptake. However I don't want to sound like the politician who suggested curing COVID-19 by injecting people with bleach.

What politician suggested injecting people with bleach?

Trump. It wasn't an actual suggestion so much as just wondering aloud during a press conference. Along the lines of "They say bleach can kill this stuff immediately. I wonder if -- could you inject that to just kind of... clean it out from inside?"

So then it wasn't suggested to inject people with it


could the water be replaced by some other compound with a lower freezing point which would either be processed by the growth medium or accepted directly by the plants?

...No
Liquid water is absolutely essential for plants, primarily because of its role in photosynthesis. Specifically, during the photolysis step, water molecules are split into oxygen, protons, and electrons by the enzyme photosystem II, a process which requires the water to be in a liquid state. Liquid water is also necessary as a solvent for transporting nutrients within and between cells, which is needed for growth.
While, as you point out, some plants can survive extreme conditions--such as freezing temperatures or even full desiccation (eg. resurrection plants that "reanimate" when conditions improve)--I don't know of any plants that can actively grow at subzero internal temperatures. Those that appear to do so on Earth rely on root systems accessing liquid water below the freezing layer of the ground or localized warming (e.g., dark-colored leaves absorbing sunlight to raise internal temperatures above atmospheric).
As for replacing water with a different compound, the idea is theoretically possible but practically completely unworkable. Any substitute would need to mimic water's properties like polarity, electron donation capabilities, and its role as a universal solvent, and even then, the plants would require extensive genetic modification to adapt their biological processes to use it. This is something we can't do yet, and I'm not sure if the result of such a re-engineering could really be still called a "plant".

Algae that grows on the underside of sea ice in temperatures slightly below 0°C does so because of salt in the water preventing it from solidifying - but it's still in liquid water.  So saying "subzero temperatures" is not what you meant.  You meant "below freezing temperatures".

The chemistry of plant life needs water and the water has to be liquid for at least some part of its lifecycle.  Plants can and do freeze and become dormant to survive winter or frosty nights, but have to thaw out again at some point to grow.  They can do this by moving water out of their extremities into their roots below ground where it's above freezing to minimize damage due to "burst pipes".   So the important thing is that plants
can survive being temporarily frozen solid but can't grow in permanently frozen solid conditions without at least some periods of thawing.

Liquid water is essential /inside/ plants but (ignoring vapour pressure issues) not necessarily /outside/ them. For example, it seems to me that it would be theoretically possible to have something in solution that depressed the freezing point but was a sufficiently large molecule in sufficiently low concentration that it didn't interfere with the osmotic effects at the root hairs. This obviously sails close to my "no antifreeze" stipulation, but I was trying to not sound like the politician who suggested curing COVID by injecting people with bleach.
